# Filling the array horizontally alternately C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to fill the array horizontally alternately such as:

[image: Filling the array horizontally alternately]

My default ArrayFill function is :

```
void fillArray(std::array<std::array<int, maxColumns>, maxRows> & array, size_t rows, size_t columns)
{
    if (rows == 0 || rows > maxRows || columns == 0 || columns > maxColumns)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid array size.");
    int value = 1;
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
        for (size_t column = 0; column < columns; ++column)
            array[row][column] = value++;
}
```

How can I change the implementation that will fill the array horizontally?

- UPDATE -

I tried the suggested solution and here is the result:

[image: ERRROR]

-- FINAL --  ( IT WORKS PERFECTLY )

[image: WORKS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two properties which you should obey:

1. start filling not from top (row=0) but bottom (row=rows-1)
2. each row (from bottom to top) changes the order of columns

so, finally it can look like this:

```
int value = 1;
int colOrder = 1; // 1 means from left to right, 0 from right to left
for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
    for (size_t column = 0; column < columns; ++column)
        array[rows - 1 - row][colOrder ? column : (columns - 1 - column)] = value++;
    colOrder ^= 1; // change column order
}
```

Comment: I tried it but I'm still getting errors

Comment: @NOBUD you have wrong test, for 3x2 you need {5,6},{4,3}.{1,2}

Comment: ahhh my bad. I'm gonna fix it.